# What is the meaning of transportation in the following paragraph?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of transportation in the following paragraph?

> "That," Donna announced, "is transportation!" A small caramel-colored cow sauntered toward us. Donna held out her hand and our "transportation" nuzzled it with a wet, velvety nose.

Comment: Did you try looking in a dictionary?

Comment: It means Donna and her companion(s) are about to ride a cow.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a mildly humourous remark, *transportation* being usually thought of as something rather more sophisticated.

Answer (score 2):

*transportation* here refers to the cow, which **Donna** purports to be their vehicle for transportation.